# Question regarding vocal range

Tags: vocal-range

I am a untrained 16 year old and my vocal range is E2 to G4# (A4 on rare occasions), so is this range good,does this make me a tenor and can I improve if I train my voice.

Comment: There are so many question such as this on this site. Of course you will improve if you train, but at 16, anything could - and will - happen, so it's an unanswerable question,which I vtc.

Answer (score 1):

The lower range limit might be meaningful.  The upper one very much depends on HOW you're singing the higher notes.  As a younger man I could just about sing EVERYONE's part when teaching a chorus (I can't any more!) but that didn't make me a soprano :-)  And voice type is about sound, not just range.  Baritones often CAN sing high tenor notes, but sound better lower down.

Anyway, at 16 you don't really know where your voice is going to end up.   Enjoy singing, don't strain, and yes, take some lessons.